# pandas.isin broken for all caps?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I found the [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) function for pandas, but it looks like all caps doesn't show?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('{"Technology Group":{"0":"Cloud","1":"Cloud","2":"Cloud","3":"Collaboration","4":"Collaboration","5":"Collaboration","6":"Collaboration","7":"Collaboration","8":"Collaboration","9":"Core", "10": "Software"},"Technology":{"0":"AMP","1":"EWS","2":"Webex","3":"Telepresence","4":"Call Manager","5":"Contact Center","6":"MS Voice","7":"Apps","8":"PRIME  ","9":"Wirelees", "10": "Prime Infrastructure"}}')

+------------------+----------------------+
| Technology Group | Technology           |
+------------------+----------------------+
| Cloud            | AMP                  |
+------------------+----------------------+
| Cloud            | EWS                  |
+------------------+----------------------+
| Cloud            | Webex                |
+------------------+----------------------+
| Collaboration    | Telepresence         |
+------------------+----------------------+
| Collaboration    | Call Manager         |
+------------------+----------------------+
| Collaboration    | Contact Center       |
+------------------+----------------------+
| Collaboration    | MS Voice             |
+------------------+----------------------+
| Collaboration    | Apps                 |
+------------------+----------------------+
| Collaboration    | PRIME                |
+------------------+----------------------+
| Core             | Wirelees             |
+------------------+----------------------+
| Software         | Prime Infrastructure |
+------------------+----------------------+

tech_input2 = ['AMP', 'Call Manager', 'PRIME']
df = df[df['Technology'].isin(tech_input2)]
```

It will show the following table:

```
+------------------+--------------+
| Technology Group | Technology   |
+------------------+--------------+
| Cloud            | AMP          |
+------------------+--------------+
| Collaboration    | Call Manager |
+------------------+--------------+
```

... instead of:

```
+------------------+--------------+
| Technology Group | Technology   |
+------------------+--------------+
| Cloud            | AMP          |
+------------------+--------------+
| Collaboration    | Call Manager |
+------------------+--------------+
| Collaboration    | PRIME        |
+------------------+--------------+
```

Is this a bug? Or did I do something wrong? It's not technically a duplicate of the original last line in the table, but not sure how to decipher it. It seems to act more like [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) than [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) ...

Comment: You have spaces in your `PRIME` string.  `isin` is looking for an exact match and not finding one.

Comment: Try df['Technology'] = df['Technology'].str.strip() and then run your code again

Comment: @user3483203 - there are 2 different Prime items. "PRIME" and "Prime Infrastructure"

Comment: @Vaishali that fixed it! :-O Are you able to create an answer so I can mark it for you?

Comment: Technically it's just a dupe plus you had a working code. May be you can delete the question

Comment: I looked - the only ones I saw were not relevant to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to spaces. The [strip()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip) removes characters from both left and right based on the argument (a string specifying the set of characters to be removed).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('{"Technology Group": {"0":"Cloud","1":"Cloud", 
"2":"Cloud","3":"Collaboration", "4":"Collaboration" ,":"Collaboration", 
"6":"Collaboration", "7":"Collaboration","8":"Collaboration","9":"Core", 
"10": "Software"},"Technology":{"0":"AMP","1":"EWS","2":"Webex","3":"Telepresence",
"4":"Call Manager","5":"Contact Center","6":"MS Voice","7":"Apps","8":"PRIME  
","9":"Wirelees", "10": "Prime Infrastructure"}}')

df['Technology'] = df['Technology'].str.strip()
tech_input2 = ['AMP', 'Call Manager', 'PRIME']
df = df[df['Technology'].isin(tech_input2)]
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. @Vaishali was able to provide the same solution but you beat them to posting a response instead of a comment. Thank you!